# ¿Como Tomar todos los id's de una variable en php?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente código, es un sistema de filtro en tiempo real, el problema que tengo es que al hacer la selección de una persona, solo toma al primer id que tenga esa persona y los demás no los muestra  $ver[0]  es donde estan los id', $ver[1] las personas.... 
Quiero que al seleccionar una persona (ejecutiva) me muestre todos los resultados que contengan esa persona y no solo el primero.

```html
<?php
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT id, ejecutiva from prosp_promo GROUP BY ejecutiva
                                ORDER BY ejecutiva" ;
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

 ?>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
  <label>Buscador</label>
  <select id="buscadorvivo" class="form-control input-sm">
   <option value="0">Seleciona uno</option>
   
   <?php
    while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)): 

    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ver[0] ?>">
     <?php echo $ver[1] ?>     
    </option>




   <?php endwhile; ?>

  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creo que te faltan las paréntesis en el while

Comment: No queda muy claro lo que quieres exactamente, pero me da la impresion que lo que necesitas es hacer un `WHERE ejecutiva = valor` y sacar el DISTINCT en la consulta.

Comment: Tu código contiene errores tipográficos, saludos.

Comment: Así es, en resumen, como puedes tener $ver[0] si apenas en ese mismo query lo voy a definir?
Como mandas llamar $ver[0] al query?